# Set dragBoundFunc in rotating shape Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs

I have already create Rectangle with dragBoundFunc using KineticJs

```
    var myrect=new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:0,
        y:0,
         width: 10,
         height: 80,
         fill:"grey",
         opacity:1,
         draggable:true,
         dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
         var newx = pos.x < 0 ? 0 : pos.x && pos.x > 150 ? 150 : pos.x
         var newy = pos.y < 0 ? 0 : pos.y && pos.y > 150 ? 150 : pos.y
         return{
         x:newx,
         y:newy
         }

         }
    })
```

So let me explain, I want to create a rectancle in a rectangle. This rectangle has a dragBoundFunc since it is in a rectangle. the problem is when I set the rotation like "myrect.setRotationDeg(90)" the dragBound was not going well because the position of this rectangle also get rotate. What must i do to get this problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate a rectangle, it’s bounding box changes size.  Here’s how to calculate that new size and use the new size to calculate the new borders of your rotated rectangle (pseudo-code):

```
var cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rotationInRadians));
var sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rotationInRadians));
var newWidth =  rectHeight * sin + rectWidth * cos;
var newHeight = rectHeight * cos + rectWidth * sin;
// assuming you rotated your rectangle around it’s center
var newLeft= rectCurrentX + rectWidth/2 – newWidth/2;
var newRight = newLeft + newWidth;
var newTop =  rectCurrentY + rectHeight/2 – newHeight/2;
var newBottom = newTop + newHeight;
```

Then plug that into your dragBoundFunc.

*Having done the math…This will probably not work!*

**Remember that your dragBoundFunc must execute every mousemove**

`dragBoundFunc` must be built to execute *very quickly*.

This solution won’t work because by the time you do all this math for the current mousemove, the user will have mousemoved 3-5 more times and escaped your drag bounds.

The math takes too long to be effective (even on my relatively fast quad-core machine).

Your working solution *probably* involves pre-calculating the bounds of your rectangle at 6-12 different rotations around 360 degrees (2PI radians).

Then in dragBoundFunc:  Plug in your current X/Y into your pre-crunched bounds and test each for violations.

Since this involves just 6-12 simple math calculations in dragBoundFunc you will probably be able to keep up with the mountain of user’s mousemoves.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'd appreciate it. But Is there any way? because I just dont use it only in dragBoundFunc. If I rotate that shape, when I call a function for example getWidth() I hope the result will be 80 not 10. Can you do some thing about it?

Comment: Well.......The only thing I can think of is to use a custom Kinetic Shape.  Kinetic.Shape allows you to access html canvas's native drawing functions to manipulate your custom shape.  That's done inside Kinetic.Shape's drawFunc. So, instead of rotating that shape, you can do a custom drawFunc that redraws a rectangle at the appropriate rotation.  Then you can set your shape's x,y,width,height without getting kinetic upset.  Alternatively, if you want a Kinetic.Rect to "know" your rotated x,y and bounds, you can always extend it: myrect.rotatedX= ... ;  My dragFunc warning still applies though!

Comment: In my case i am actualy using image instead Rect. can we just rotate the image without using kineticjs. for example we use transform funtion in css and apply it in kieticjs?

Comment: Is any single image always rotated to the same angle?  For example: image#1=45degrees, image#2=135degrees--with no change ever in either angle?

Comment: actualy i only provide 4 angles which are 0, 90, 180, and 270. If user want to rotate they must click a button "rotate" to rotate  it.

Comment: Limiting angles to 0/90/180/270 makes this task simpler.  Here’s code that adds rX, rY, rWidth, rHeight functions to each image.  These functions get the **rotated values** of x,y,width,height.  The same example also shows how to constrain a rotated image in a rectangle using dragFunc:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/PqA6W/